# The Ajax GET request gives me an error 500

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am a student and im currently working on a php project. When the below code is executed im getting an error 500. 
project.js

```
$('#project[enter image description here][1]Modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var projectid = el.data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url: 'project.php',
            data: {'projectid':projectid},
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    var tot = data.amount+parseFloat(amount);
                    modal.find('#totalAmt').html(tot);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
               alert(exception);
            }
        });
    });
```

project.php

```
<?php
include_once '../config.php';
if (isset($_GET['projectid'])) {
    $projectId = strip_tags($_POST['projectid']);
    $query = "SELECT SUM(amount) as sum FROM pledge WHERE project_id=$projectid";
    $amount = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die(mysql_error());
    return $amount;
}
?>
```

Below is the config.php

```
<?php

$databaseHost = 'localhost';
$databaseName = 'lyceum';
$databaseUsername = 'root';
$databasePassword = 'la#3478';

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $databaseName);

?>
```

Below is the project structure,
lyceum 
        js 
           project.js 
        project
          science_project.php
          project.php
config.php

Can anyone please help me with the error? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: just return json_encode on php part

Comment: couple of errors i see: its $_GET['projectid'] not $_POST['projectid']. mysqli_query returns an object, not the value from the select. strip_tags() has no use here, has no security features, dont use this code in prodcution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053424/7362396 how to enable errors (then check full response in DevTools). And as others have mentioned you need to convert the DB result object to JSON.

Comment: The reason for the 500 error will be in your HTTP server's error log

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is you are attempting to `return` your values.
PHP can't be returned like that, your Javascript and PHP are part of entirely separate callstacks. Whilst this isn't causing your 500 error, you've got other errors in here will.

At the beginning of your `project.php` you'll need to add `header('Content-type: application/json');` Your AJAX call automatically expects JSON, and will treat any response it gets as JSON. However if you wished to use this elsewhere this may prevent errors.

Also, your `$amount` gives you a mysqli_result object, you'll need to use something like `$values = mysqli_fetch_assoc($amount)` to get the values required.

Then, instead of `return`ing you'll need to `echo json_encode($values['sum'])` and if you do not want program execution to continue (like return does) you'll also need to `exit()` or `die()` after the echo.

Your `die()` on your `$amount` line also has an error and should take `mysqli_error()` instead `mysql_error()`

I also suggest looking at prepared statements to protect your queries from SQL injection here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Avoid posting your database details. You never know how long your project, or this question will be around for. If your database is used for something publicly used, and you store sensitive information, someone could've taken this password a long time ago and could get write access to it.

Comment: Adding a `Content-type` response header is fantastic advice but it's worth pointing out OP has `dataType: 'json'` in their client-side code which overwrites any default handling

Comment: I see! I'll amend that now.

Comment: Also, `$amount` will be a `mysqli_result` object and not something that can be encoded as JSON. Data will need to be _fetched_ from the DB

Comment: Thanks for the answer but even if I do the above changes I get the below error
jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/lyceum/projects/project.php?projectid=1 500 (Internal Server Error)
jquery.min.js:4 XHR failed loading: GET "http://localhost/lyceum/projects/project.php?projectid=1".

Comment: Having `return` won't trigger a 500 error though so that shouldn't be the reason for the OP's error. It should simply result in an empty response. The OP needs to check the servers error log (or enable "display_errors" and read the response of the request) to see what actually happens.

Comment: Amended. Hopefully this should fix it a little more. May I recommend getting some debugging software like XDebug. It saved me in times like this.

Answer (score 0):

To make `project.js` work your `project.php` should look like

```
include_once '../config.php';
if (isset($_GET['projectid'])) {
    $projectId = strip_tags($_POST['projectid']);
    $query = "SELECT SUM(amount) as sum FROM pledge WHERE project_id=$projectid";
    $amount = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die(mysql_error());

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = TRUE;
    $response["amount"] = $amount;

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: What have you changed that would solve a 500 error? The OP should also use Prepared Statements instead of `strip_tags()` (which has zero relevance in this context) and injecting the user input totally unescaped into the query.

Comment: the code looks good, to fix 500 we will need more info or error logs, but the JS code is expecting json response so this change is required, even if he manage to fix 500 error the JS code will not work if response is not in json format

Comment: also mixing post\get

Comment: Since we don't know what's causing the 500 error (which is what the OP posted the question about), we should simply wait with giving answers until the OP comes back with more info.